# Unable to save both Raw and Jpeg file at the same time occaionally in xt-20

Tags: fujifilm-x-t20

The attached photo shows my desired settings: "Raw F" (2nd rows, third from the left) in non-auto mode.

[image]

However for some reason this option is not available to me.

Sometimes if I use the 'Q' button, I can see the settings are limited to only 'F' and 'N'.

It seems like if I cycle through the profiles (in this case it is now set to 'Base C 1', I can get the raw options again.

Have other Xt-20 encountered this issue? If so, how can I always get the Raw options?

Comment: My question is about producing RAW in non-auto mode

Comment: Without *detailed* settings info, it's impossible to know which feature you're using is disabling raw.

Comment: Agreed. I should have taken a picture when it happened.

Answer (score 1):

Raw is disabled when any one of a number of features is enabled.  They include various toy camera modes, extended ISO, and the auto switch.

Without detailed settings info, it's impossible to know which feature you've used that has disabled raw.  Figure out which features you use that disable raw. Then stop using them.